How to adjust my external custom library import in __init__.py?
So I have a big folder called Geometry and I divided in CPP folder and Cython folder as follows.
- Geometry
 - CPP (Where all the cpp codes are)
 - Cython
  - src folder
   - Geometry Package
    - Point Package
     - __init__.py
     - libcustom.so
    - Circle Package
     - __init__.py
     - libcustom.so
     - __init__.py (Ignore this file)
    - libcustom.so
  - test folder
  - setup.py

In Point.__init__.py and Circle.__init__.py, I have to add the following
import ctypes
import os
libcustom = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libcustom.so"))

Now as you can see, in order for my libcustom to work on all packages including Point and Circle, I have to add the libcustom.so in both Point and Circle, which doesn't look so good.
Now I want to remove all libcustom.so from Point and Circle and only keep the one outside.
- Geometry
     - CPP (Where all the cpp codes are)
     - Cython
      - src folder
       - Geometry Package
        - Point Package
         - __init__.py
        - Circle Package
         - __init__.py
        - libcustom.so
        - __init__.py (Ignore this file)
      - test folder
      - setup.py

How should I change my Point.__init__.py and Circle.__init__.py code so that it will point a reference to the libcustom.so outside?

Try [Python.Docs]: os.path.dirname(path) twice.
DLL_NAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), "libcustom.so")

Or you could use (more modern) [Python.Docs]: pathlib - Object-oriented filesystem paths.
DLL_NAME = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1].joinpath("libcustom.so"))

Note: I assume that "libElements.so" in your snippet is a mistake.

Seems like it's not working for me

When stating something make sure to include all the relevant details, in order to go further. What is not working? How did you try and is not working? Did you print the path to see if it matches the file location on disk?

libCustom = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_NAME)

/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py:374: in __init__

self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

I just double checked my code. Actually it worked. I made a typo with my library name. Thank you sir
